# Terminology for partial offline database synchronization

Tags: database, terminology, synchronization, offline

I am looking for solutions for a field where I think I don't know the adequate terminology. The problem is that I have a central SQL database in the cloud. Then I have child databases only containing a defined part of the central database. The child database will not always have connection to the main database but as soon as they have they should synchronize the data they have.

What is the terminology for such a system? It is about offline availability of data but also about synchronization of subset of data available in the central database.

Comment: Are you referring to a [Distributed database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database)?

Comment: Another term that might help is `database sharding`

Comment: Sharding usually involves the segregation of readings and writings. Each shard is focused on specific writes and reads. The closer definition of OP's configuration is just "replica". Replica sets usually replicate all the main (Primary) DB. It's mainly for HA and high failure tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

The general term for having off-line "child" databases is [replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)). I don't believe there is standard term for those child databases only containing a defined part of the central database. Call it partial replication, if you like.